# How to read gps data continuously using arduino pro mini

Tags: json, arduino, gps

I am working on a project where i capture the temperature & humidity, gps, and gyrometer data and construct a json out of all these and send to serial port. I am able to do for the temeperature, humidity and gyrometer, but not able to get the data from the GPS.

Modules used are

1. DHT11 for temperature and humidity
2. ADXL for gyrometer readings
3. GY NMEO6MV2 for GPS

This is the code snippet for GPS

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
dht DHT;
// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
// Defining pin for humidity sensor
#define DHT11_PIN 7
// Defining pin for ADXL Analog pins
const int xPin = 3;
const int yPin = 4;
const int zPin = 5;
//ADXL Data
double x,y,z;
// Defining Static values ADXL. TO CHANGE AS NEEDED
int xStatic = 504;
int yStatic = 493;
int zStatic = 617;
void setup()
{      
  //int error;
  //uint8_t c;
  Serial.begin(19200);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}
void loop()
{
  //int error;
  //double dT;
  //char buffer[100];
  //read the analog values from the accelerometer
  int xRead = analogRead(xPin);
  int yRead = analogRead(yPin);
  int zRead = analogRead(zPin);
  x = xStatic - xRead;
  y = yStatic - yRead;
  z = zStatic - zRead;
  //Serial.print("{\"x\":");
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print("#");
  //Serial.print(",\"y\":");
  Serial.print(y);
  Serial.print("#");
 //Serial.print(",\"z\":");
 Serial.print(z);
 //DHT
 if (int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN)) {
   Serial.print("#");
   //Serial.print(",\"temperature\":");
   Serial.print(DHT.temperature);
   Serial.print("#");
   //Serial.print(",\"humidity\":");
   Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
 }
 while (ss.available() > 0)
    if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
       if(gps.location.isValid())
       {
        //Serial.print(",\"latitude\":");
          Serial.print("#");
          Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
       // Longitude in degrees (double)
        //Serial.print(",\"longitude\":");
          Serial.print("#");
          Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
       //DATE
          String date;
          // Day (1-31) (u8)
          date= gps.date.day();
          // Month (1-12) (u8)
          date+= "-";
          date+= gps.date.month();
          // Year (2000+) (u16)
          date+= "-";
          date+= gps.date.year();
          //Serial.print(",\"date\":");
          Serial.print("#");
          Serial.print("\""+date+"\"");
          //TIME
          String time;
          // Hour (0-23) (u8)
          time= gps.time.hour();
          time+= ":";
          // Minute (0-59) (u8)
          time+= gps.time.minute();
          time+= ":";
          // Second (0-59) (u8)
          time+= gps.time.second();
          time+= ":";
          // 100ths of a second (0-99) (u8)
          time+= gps.time.centisecond();
          //Serial.print(",\"time\":");
          Serial.print("#");
          Serial.print("\""+time+"\"");
          //GPS SPEED AND ALTITUDE
          // Speed in kilometers per hour (double)
          Serial.print("#");
          //Serial.print(",\"speed\":");
          Serial.print(gps.speed.kmph());
          //Serial.println("}");
          //Serial.println("$");
          delay(2000);
   }
   Serial.print("$");
   delay(3000);
   if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
   {
     Serial.println(F("No GPS detected: check wiring."));
     while(true);
   }

 }
```

The values are not coming continuously from the gps.
Can any one help me out in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which pro mini 3.3 or 5V? How did you set up the serial port ? How did you wire up the GPS unit ? Can you verify its even sending ANY data, getting a GPS fix ? Not continuously = sometimes does ?

Comment: and which GPS library?

Comment: I don't see your setup and loop functions in your code

Comment: @lostbard the board which i am using supports both 3.3v and 5v, and library is TInyGPS++

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki please have a look at code now

Comment: What you mean by "The values are not coming continuously from the gps"? GPS usually transmit data location at 1Hz

Comment: @Lucky but what is the boards IO configured for? it will be one or the other, not both

Comment: @lostbard it is connected to 3.3V

Comment: First of all check that Baud is configured for the GPS, by default these GSP modules are configured at 9600, but in any case it is advisable that you verify it